# RNN fails to fit a linear trend (Keras BPTT issue?)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to train a simple LSTM to fit a line. My hypothesis is that I should be able to fit a linearly decreasing trend with zero input since the LSTM can decide how much it listens to its input vs. internal state, and can thus learn to just operate on the internal state. Basically a degenerate case for testing whether the LSTM can fit an expected result with zero input.

I create my input and target data:

```
seq_len = 1000    
x_train = np.zeros((1, seq_len, 1))  # [batch_size, seq_len, num_feat]
target = np.linspace(100, 0, num=seq_len).reshape(1, -1, 1)
```

I create a pretty simple network:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Input, TimeDistributed

x_in = Input((seq_len, 1))
seq1 = LSTM(8, return_sequences=True)(x_in)
dense1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(8))(seq1)
seq2 = LSTM(8, return_sequences=True)(dense1)
dense2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(8))(seq2)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(dense2)

model = Model(inputs=x_in, outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

history = model.fit(x_train, target, batch_size=1, epochs=1000,
                    validation_split=0.)
```

I also created a custom callback that calls `model.predict(x_train)` after every epoch and adds the results to an array so I can see how my model's output is evolving over time. Basically the model just learns to predict a constant value which gradually (asymptotically) approaches the mean of my target line (target line is in red, not sure why the legend didn't show):

[image: Epoch prediction history]

So basically nothing is driving my response to fit the actual line, I'm just gradually approaching the *mean* of the line. I suspect I am not getting any gradient with respect to time (data index), just an average gradient over time. But I would have thought LSTM losses would automagically give you gradient through time.

I've tried:

- different activation functions for the LSTM layers (`None`, `'relu'` for both the regular activation and recurrent activation)
- different optimizers (`'nadam'`, `'adadelta'`, `'rmsprop'`)
- the `'mean_aboslute_error'` loss function, which I didn't expect to improve the results, and it acted about the same
- passing sequences of random numbers drawn from a normal distribution as input
- replacing `LSTM` with `GRU`

Nothing seems to do it.

Anybody have a suggestion as to how I can force this thing to train on the gradient as a function of my sequence index, i.e. `g(t)`? Or any other suggestions on how I can get this to work?

**Note:** with the trend as shown, if the LSTM results in a constant value at exactly the mean (50), the minimum mean absolute error will be 25 and the minimum mean squared error will be about 835.8. So if we don't see any better than that, we probably aren't fitting the line, just the mean.

Just some references in case you run this yourself.

Comment: To whoever voted to close: breh, this is exactly on topic. It's specific, reproducible, contains a minimal complete example, and pertains to a specific programming problem or algorithm. Literally the definition of [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).